How do the capacitors affect the performance as a generator of a permanent magnet, brushed DC motor?
I have a 24V 24A brushed DC motor (from a old pump so quite big in size).
It has permanent magnets on around the coils, and the coils are wound around iron.
Just like many brushed DC motors it has capacitors connected between the brushes.
When using it as a DC motor these capacitors make a lot of sense as they make the current to the motor more stable as well as might help protect against some induction voltage peaks.
However, as in this case it will be used as a generator, I wondered:
Do those capacitors also give a notable effect on its use as a generator?
And if so how/what/when/why?
As in improving or decreasing the power generation.
Next to that I also wondered if like normal coils wound around a iron core those coils in such a motor will also generate some form of reverse voltage peaks on the outputs, and so if it might make sense to remove those capacitors, and add a rectifier, or reverse voltage discharge diode and only after that add some capacitors to stabilize it?
Next to that when measuring it with a multimeter it also measures AC voltage.
So there is a potential tradeoff.
As rectifying produces a form of resistance and voltage drop often, but would allow to use the potentially generated side AC signals.
Meanwhile a capacitor would cancel those out and potentially slightly discharge from the ac signals, but would greatly lower the relative resistance at the output thus generating more power at a lower rpm.

this site is not a chat forum ... your post goes into chat mode after and if so how/what/when/why? ... please edit your post to focus on one question

What value capacitors?

the values doesn't matter yet, as it is a theoretical question.
in more simple words it is about that a brushed DC motor seems to also generate some AC spikes on it's output, but can't see if it is true ac or adc,.
neither how much power. so largely wondered if when using a brushed dc motor to generate bigger amounts of power if it would be better to add a capacitor(probably big) to the outputs so that as much current can be discharged as rapidly as possible to the outputs/generated). or if it might make sense to first rectify the outputs.
